# What constitutes a chess ecosystem?

Tags: tournament, clubs

I'm been thinking about the metrics to measure to make a "Best Cities for Chess" list. Assume I'm going to call these cities as "Chess Ecosystems", what are some of the things that would indicate its health?

ex: Number of FIDE rated players, tournaments organized every year, coaches available, etc.

What will you add to this list ?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters I can think of:

Number of

- Chess club members
- FIDE rated players
- FIDE titled players
- Grandmasters
- Female players
- Tournaments
- Seminars / lectures

I'm not sure how to convert these parameters into a final score, nevertheless I'm curious how the list of best chess cities would look like. I would expect Moscow to be clear number one (many resident grandmasters, many tournaments). I'm also wondering how good [Saint-Louis](http://saintlouischessclub.org/) would score.